# How to display rails app's page inside another page of this app with iframe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, iframe, http-headers

I have to display my page, which is the part of my app, on this app's another page inside an iframe

E.g. I have `/customers` page and /invoices page (both actions are `#index`). `/invoices` page has iframe with `src='http://localhost:3000/customers'`.

How to make it work correctly (also in production, means `example.com/invoices` has to display `example.com/customer` inside an iframe)?

I've already tried other solutions from StackOverflow:

- `response.headers.delete('X-Frame-Options')` inside `CustomerController#index` (and `before_action` & `after_action` too)
- set `config.action_dispatch.default_headers = { 'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL' }`
- delete headers on `ApplicationController` level as in `CustomerController`
- Set `response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'ALLOWALL'`

But nothing works. Each time I get `localhost refused to connect.` in Chrome and `Firefox Can’t Open This Page` in Firefox.

It also doesn't work with relative path, such as `iframe src='/customers'`

Comment: Just a small doubt, did you try restarting the server and see?

Comment: Sure, I've also tried to run the app in production env, but this didn't get any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution in HTTP headers.
Checked out Content-Security-Policy header and in was set to `none` in `config/initializers/secure_headers.rb`

So the problem solution is in setting up `frame_ancestors: %w['self']`

```
SecureHeaders::Configuration.default do |config|
  config.csp = {
    ...
    frame_ancestors:         %w['self'], # Replaced from frame_ancestors: %w['none'],
    ...
  }
end
```

And checkout HTTP headers, that `Content-Security-Policy` header contains `frame-ancestors 'self';`

It works in dev such as in production